Trapping error and alerting after invoking rest calls from Powershell
I'm trying to trap the errors and alert after invoking rest calls from Powershell. However I trtied the try/catch and trap Errorlevel $? nothing is working.
My Powershell version:
PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  6343  

Code
  # Define the API endpoint URL
$url = "https://urliswrong.com/api/1/rest/slsched/feed/SNOWFLAKE/snow_main?TABLE_NAME=temp1234"


#Url is wrong and The table temp1234 doesn't exists

$token = "SuperSecuretoken"


  try
    {
        $Error.Clear()

    # Create a custom header with the Bearer Token
    $headers = @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
    }
    
    # Make the GET request with custom headers
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    #$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers -StatusCodeVariable 'statusCode'
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing
    if  ( $? -eq 'False' )
    {
    echo "Issue with the script"
         exit 1
         }
    $StatusCode = $response.StatusCode
    echo $StatusCode
    }
    catch
    {
    $StatusCode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
    echo $StatusCode
    
    }
     echo $StatusCode

Output after execution of the above code is empty, it should say something (atleast a http 404) because the URL is wrong. Could you please let me know what am I missing in this code?

There is no Response property (and, hence, no StatusCode)  for the exception since the error you are getting is not from an HTTP response - since the URL is invalid, it never even gets to the point of making the web call - it fails at the name lookup stage.  You can see this by changing urliswrong.com to google.com in your example URL.  You should get a 404 status.

Thanks for the response, I change to any url (working or non-working) there is no output.

Odd.  If I take your code and change only the second line, I get 404 as the output: $url = "https://google.com/api/1/rest/slsched/feed/SNOWFLAKE/snow_main?TABLE_NAME=temp1234".  Are you using this exact code or a modified version?
